# Question being marked as a duplicate of another with general troubleshooting steps

Tags: discussion, specific-question, moderation

I posted [this question here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/258182/metasploit-payload-not-working-over-publicly-hosted-ip?noredirect=1&lq=1) trying to get specific help on how to deploy a metasploit payload via a tunneling service called [pagekite](https://pagekite.net/support/quickstart/). My question was closed and marked as a duplicate of [another question with an answer from a mod to general troubleshooting steps](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/257861/271793).

I am a beginner to networking and pen-testing in general, but I tried the troubleshooting steps, could not find a solution, and thus edited the question to include the results of my troubleshooting. In my opinion, asking for more information regarding what I was doing and linking the troubleshooting steps would have been more justified than closing the question altogether and marking it as a duplicate. But even after including additional information about the results of my troubleshooting, my question was still kept closed.

My question here is: if someone is asking for help regarding a specific issue here is it justified to just close their question and link to a guide on how to troubleshoot the problem themselves? The same troubleshooting steps I was given could apply to anyone with any metasploit issue that they could not resolve. To me that's the same as giving someone who can't get their code working a guide to using the debugger and not giving any specific insight on what they could be doing wrong.

Should I ask my question again and change it in some other way or should I just give up on getting help altogether?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Schroeder left you a very specific note in the chat linked under your question:

> The problem is that this isn't a security issue. You have a networking issue. We get so many questions like this ("my payload doesn't connect back to me") and every single one is a basic networking issue. You have discovered that your payload is not making a connection to the pagekite. That's good. Now you need to troubleshoot that. This simply isn't a security matter

So the troubleshooting post does answer what you need to do.

You do need to follow the guidance we give on our help pages to ensure you ask questions appropriate for this site.